# Maximum Clock Determination in Xilinx ISE 14.4

Tags: verilog, clock, xilinx

I have a piece of code implemented in Verilog which calculates centroid of an image.
I have simulated the code using Xilinx ISIM simulator in Post place and route mode and it works well, now I want to determine the maximum clock speed at which the code can run.
The Design summary in its Clock report indicates that Max Delay is 0.057 nsec does that mean I can have a clock speed less than 1/0.057 nsec or is there any other indication of maximum possible clock speed.

Answer (score 1):

there are several factors in determining this, and you may need more information that just max delay (for instance jitter, hold times, setup times, etc). The clock speed will certainly not be less then 1/.057ns which is equal to 17GHz. Also, what is your target for this design? because if it is for an FPGA then you will not be able to  go past the specs for your current chip.

If you go to your xst.log file (that is if you had vivado/ISE print out a report then) and you go to the bottom of that file it will give you a timing summary. one of those lines will say:

Minimum period: x ns (Maximum Frequency: X MHz) this will tell you how fast you can run.

Comment: I think vivado dont output the maximumx frequency anymore. They just tell you wether it can meet the constrained frequency or not (the argumentation behind it, is that those guessed valued are no serious max frequency, as it can only be validated when synth, placed and routed with the required timing constraint).

Comment: vivado.log has the printout of the timing analysis at the bottom of the log file. It should be noted that flol is correct that you will only get the best guess for timing at each checkpoint.

Also, you will only print out a vivado log if you tell it to at certain checkpoints, this is done in the script or through the gui that you are using. 

A good way to do testing is to set the frequency to some very high or your goal frequency and it will tell you how far off you are after it has put a lot of effort into pnr. because if you have a low frequency the tool will not try very hard to min timing